# ASP.NET Session identifier

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

I'm trying to make a session code for each client on my site. In the Session_Start of the global asax I have this code:

```
private static long codSesion = 0;
private static object codSesionLocker = new object();
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["CodSesion"] == null)
    {
        lock (codSesionLocker)
        {
            if (Session["CodSesion"] == null)
            {
                if (codSesion == 9999)
                    codSesion = 0;
                codSesion++;
                Session["CodSesion"] = codSesion;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I monitor this it seems to be perfect. After some time of inactivity starts the problems. One of the thing that happens is that too many times starts over from 1 (without reaching 9999 and without IIS rebouting). And recently, even worst than taht: I'd used the codes 1 and 2. I stop using the server (leting the IIS without activity). After almost 1 hour (50 minutes) I tried again. The code the IIS gave me was 2 (in a different PC than the last code 2).

Please I'd realy apreciate any help with this.

Comment: Do you have any code that actually accesses the session on requests you made?

Comment: And BTW, why you aren't okay with this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The session has already an id: SessionID...

Comment: @Restuta, @Yves M. - SessonID is not simple and readable as I'd like this number to be.

Comment: But it works =) Who needs readability of the Session ID?

Comment: @Restuta - I do. I need to show the value in a grid, if I show Session ID it wont be very usefull and will take too many time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this explains all of the behavior you listed above, but by default, the application pool in IIS will recycle after a period of inactivity (these settings can be changed in IIS for each application pool).  When the application pool recycles, then the new instance of the pool will be completely reinitialized.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually what was happening. I've implemented @rdkleine solution (save codSesion in a file) and now it works

Answer (score 2):

IIS recycles the worker process and there you'll lose the static value of codSession.

Save the information in a file or database to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2):

After a certain period of inactivity, IIS will stop your application. Once somebody visits, the site will start again. Combine that with the fact that you're probably using In Processes Session State and that is why you are seeing the value reset.

You could try to use SqlServer to store the Session as described here so that the data is persisted:

[MSDN - ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

Even if that works, trying to use Session in this fashion is a bad idea. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there is a better way to handle things.